# Deform - render input type to be number not text

Tags: html, deform, colander

So my problem is I want Deform render an input type number like this:

```
 <input type="number" name="end" value="" id="deformField4" class=" form-control ">
```

instead of:

```
 <input type="text" name="end" value="" id="deformField4" class=" form-control ">
```

from a source like this:

```
...
end = SchemaNode(
    colander.Integer(),
    title=_(u"End value"),
    validator=deferred_something
)
```

What can I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding a class "is_number" and then changing type attr with jQuery:

```
end = SchemaNode(
    colander.Integer(),
    widget=TextInputWidget(css_class='is_number'),
    title=_(u"End value"),
    validator=deferred_add_multi_problems_validator
)
```